Redirect in Remix On Page Load
What's the best way to redirect on page load in remix? Isn't my code below bad or calling unnecessarily?
My base route on my website always starts with /orderId. I have a navigation menu labeled "products". On that "products" page, there is another menu navbar containing /orderId/products/local and /orderId/products/global. When I navigate to the "products" page, I want to be immediately redirected to /orderId/products/local.
import { type LoaderFunctionArgs, redirect } from "@remix-run/node";
import { Outlet, useLocation } from "@remix-run/react";
import OrderLink from "~/components/order-link";
import { Tabs, TabsList, TabsTrigger } from "~/components/ui/tabs";

export const loader = async ({ request, params }: LoaderFunctionArgs) => {
    const orderId = params["order-id"];
    const url = new URL(request.url);
    const pathname = url.pathname;

    if (pathname === `/${orderId}/products` || pathname === `/${orderId}`) {
        return redirect(`/${orderId}/products/local`);
    }

    return null;
};

export default function Products() {
    const location = useLocation();
    const tabValue = location.pathname.includes("/local") ? "local" : "global";

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="flex items-center justify-between w-full mb-10">
                <span className="text-xl font-semibold">Products</span>
            </div>
            <Tabs value={tabValue}>
                <TabsList className="rounded-lg w-fit">
                    <TabsTrigger asChild value="global">
                        <OrderLink to="/products/global">Global</OrderLink>
                    </TabsTrigger>
                    <TabsTrigger asChild value="local">
                        <OrderLink to="/products/local">Local</OrderLink>
                    </TabsTrigger>
                </TabsList>
                <Outlet />
            </Tabs>
        </div>
    );
}


You should create an index route that handles the redirect.
So for /:order-id/products => /:order-id/products/local
// routes/$order-id.products._index.tsx
export function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  return redirect(`${url.pathname}/local`)
}
export default function() {
  return null
}

And for /:order-id => /:order-id/products/local
// routes/$order-id._index.tsx
export function loader({ request }: LoaderFunctionArgs) {
  const url = new URL(request.url)
  return redirect(`${url.pathname}/products/local`)
}
export default function() {
  return null
}

